# KeyValue Pair XML parsing with PHP?

Tags: php, xml

I am not a developer but I am tasked with figuring out how to get this done. Please don't flog me right away.

I am trying to use PHP to parse XML files made up of key=value pairs and for the life of me, I can't get the actual values of data out of the file.

I am trying to do this using simplexml_load_file()

Q#1: Am I going about this the right way (using SimpleXML) or should I be using something else?

Here is the one of the code bits I have been trying to use:

```
<?php
$mydata = simplexml_load_file('myDataFile.xml');

   foreach ($mydata as $key1 => $value1) {
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     echo $key1;
     echo '<br>';
     echo '<br>';
     if($key1 === "measData"){
            echo "managedElement localDn";
            echo '<br>';
      }
     }      
?>
```

Here is another bit of code I explored with no luck:

```
<?php
include 'myDataFile.xml';

$data = new SimpleXMLElement(myDataFile.xml);

echo $measData->measInfo[0]->measValue;
?>
```

Here is an example of the XML file I'm trying to parse.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="MeasDataCollection.xsl"?>
<measCollecFile xmlns="http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/32_series/32.435#measCollec">
    <fileHeader fileFormatVersion="32.435 V10.0" vendorName="Ericsson AB">
        <fileSender localDn="ManagedElement=1" elementType="ERIC-COREMW_RUNTIME"/>
        <measCollec beginTime="2018-07-05T19:25:00-04:00"/>
    </fileHeader>
    <measData>
        <managedElement localDn="ManagedElement=1" swVersion="CXP9020355_2 R6C04"/>
        <measInfo measInfoId="CscfActiveUserUtilization">
            <job jobId="CscfActiveUserUtilization"/>
            <granPeriod duration="PT300S" endTime="2018-07-05T19:30:00-04:00"/>
            <repPeriod duration="PT300S"/>
            <measType p="1">cscfActiveUsersPerProfile</measType>
            <measValue measObjLdn="advanced">
                <r p="1">0</r>
            </measValue>
            <measValue measObjLdn="personal">
                <r p="1">0</r>
            </measValue>
            <measValue measObjLdn="professional">
                <r p="1">0</r>
            </measValue>
        </measInfo>
        <measInfo measInfoId="CscfBasicSipRequestHandling">
            <job jobId="CscfBasicSipRequestHandling"/>
            <granPeriod duration="PT300S" endTime="2018-07-05T19:30:00-04:00"/>
            <repPeriod duration="PT300S"/>
            <measType p="1">cscfNotifySuccess</measType>
            <measValue measObjLdn="DEFAULT">
                <r p="1">2</r>
            </measValue>
        </measInfo>........
```

I've been playing around with this several days and still can't get any actual data or values from the XML.

Q#2: How would you go about using PHP to parse this file?

Anything at all would help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a simple example using [`DOM`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) that only extracts `managedElements`, but you can call `getElementsByTagName()` again on an element if needed to do deeper search.

```
$doc = DOMDocument::load($file);

$elements = $doc->getElementsByTagName("managedElement");

foreach($elements as $element) {
  $dn = $element->getAttribute("localDn");

  var_dump($dn);
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion has gotten me further than I've been in days! Like water for a man who is dying of thirst! Thank you. I will play with this and see how far I can get.